# Why did moving all my partitions not break GRUB?

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, grub

I had a Windows/ArchLinux dual boot for a few years, and I decided a few days ago that I wanted to ditch Windows entirely (since I only used it 1% of the time) and put it in a VM instead.

I burned Fedora onto a USB drive (no particular reason behind the choice of distribution, I just wanted a working desktop environment to avoid having to use the command line for partition manipulation) and booted from it. I installed [GParted](https://gparted.org/) and went to work.

I had installed Windows first, so all the Microsoft partitions were at the start of my single SSD (a 512GB NVMe drive), with the Linux partitions (one for `/` and one for `/home`) right afterwards. I wiped the Windows ones (not the EFI partition though), resized the Linux `/home` one to occupy the maximum amount of space possible, and moved them both to the beginning of my disk space, right after the EFI partition which also got shifted by a few MBs.

I then rebooted, fully expecting my system to die on me, but everything worked fine. I just had to update my GRUB config and remove Windows from my EFI partition.

Later though, I was asking myself : **how did GRUB still know where my Linux image was, letting me boot it up without any issues, despite the fact that every partition had been moved**?

This question most likely stems from a lack of understanding of GRUB and EFI partitions (which I assume GRUB relies on at least to some degree to find out where the Linux/Windows boot files are). Nevertheless, I'm curious about it and I can't get a straight answer out of search engines, since I assume the answer is obvious when you know more about the internal workings at play here.

Comment: What is in `/etc/fstab` file? Perhaps you set up partitions to be identified by UUID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the boot components keep track of the physical position of your kernel image. That's something LILO used to do a few decades ago, but even PC BIOS bootloaders have mostly grown out of it.

Instead, both GRUB 2 and the EFI firmware actually understand partition tables and filesystems. The partition is usually indicated either by its GPT "partition GUID" or by its "filesystem UUID", not by its index nor physical position – and the files are accessed by their path within the filesystem.

This applies to all stages of the boot process:

- All EFI firmware has support for FAT, MBR, and GPT; it finds GRUB within your EFI System Partition based on the GPT "partition GUID" and the FAT file path stored within the EFI NVRAM.
- The GRUB core image contains the necessary partition and filesystem drivers embedded into it, and finds grub.cfg according to the "filesystem GUID" embedded directly into the grubx64.efi file. (This image is built by 'grub-install' and contains whatever is necessary to access /boot/grub, be it GPT, Ext4, or ZFS.)
- The grub.cfg file (built by 'grub-mkconfig') similarly specifies the path to kernel and initramfs by a combination of filesystem UUID and the file path. Additional drivers can be loaded into GRUB at this point (e.g. if your kernel is on a Btrfs filesystem that's encrypted using LUKS).
- Finally, once the Linux kernel is running, its command line (again from grub-mkconfig) also references the `/` or `root=` filesystem by its UUID (usually the filesystem UUID, but a GPT partition GUID can also be used). The initramfs image has the necessary drivers to mount the rootfs.

Comment: And the game continues with `/etc/fstab`, which can also be based on filesystem labels or UUIDs instead of device nodes. There are some people who are trying to standardize certain "well-known" UUIDs which would even allow you to boot without any configuration at all, e.g. "UUID x is always `/` and UUID y is always `/home`" and so on. This effort has however not gained any traction as far as I can see.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: I haven't heard of any such attempts to define well-known filesystem UUIDs. Are you sure you're not confusing filesystem UUIDs with GPT "partition type" GUIDs? The latter do have a few type-GUIDs for "Linux /home", etc. defined by the systemd project, though the overall concept of well-known partition type GUIDs is as old as UEFI and they have nothing to do with the UUIDs (nor PARTUUIDs) that you'd specify in /etc/fstab. (Yes, these Linux-specific IDs aren't very widespread but from what I heard, they're more meant for systemd's container thing rather than bare metal systems.)

Comment: Sorry for the late response and for accepting the answer a month later. This explains it, and is a very well-written answer to boot. Thanks!